# LeCun paper on deeplearning (Nature, 2015)

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, backpropagation

As I was reading Y. LeCun's paper on Deep Learning `(Nature, vol. 521, 2015)`, I came across a figure (the 1st one in the paper) which was associated to the backward pass during `backpropagation` through a convolutional network. I understood everything apart from the very last sentence of the legend that accompanied the figure: "Once the $\frac{∂E}{∂zk}$
is known, the error-derivative for the weight $w_{jk}$ on the connection from unit j in the layer below is just $y_j\cdot\frac{∂E}{∂zk}$".

It must be purely mathematical but I can't figure out why the error-derivative mentioned above equal $y_j$ times $\frac{∂E}{∂zk}$. Can someone explain to me this result?

Thx.

PS : link to the figure mentioned above is https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Multilayer-neural-networks-and-backpropagation-a-A-multi-layer-neural-network-shown-by_fig4_277411157

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d14TUNcbn1k

As far as I understand, in `backpropagation`, we need to multiply the local gradient of each node by the gradient from the upper level and this is the value that we send back